# Facebook is not allowing me to post to user's offline friend's walls

Tags: facebook, posts

So, my app allows users to post to their friends walls. However, offlate, I get a "Cannot Post to User's Wall" error from facebook when posting to an offline friend. The exact code works for friends who are online. Is there something else that needs to be done? I am using publish_actions permission.

See below of permissions and code:

Permissions - scope=email,publish_actions&grant_type=client_credentials

Posting code -

```
FB.ui(
                    {
                        method: 'feed',
                        link: linktocanvaspage,
                        picture: imageLink,
                        name: title,
                        caption: ' ',
                        description: (description),
                        to: id
                    },
function(response) {
//Do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

publish_actions is not required in order to publish some messages in user's wall.

If you obtain the erreor "Cannot post to user's Wall", maybe the user has blcoked his wall in his privacy settings ;-).